# Javascript return file from web service

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, download

I am trying to make a file download using javascript from a web service. The web service return data in JSON string with format below:

```
{
    "status": "OK",
    "encodedFile": "AAAAX3JlbHMvLnJlbHOtksFOwzAMhu99iij31d2QEEJNd0FIu01oPEBI3DZqE0eJB+XtiZAQDDHYgWOS358/W2m3i5/FM6bsKCi5rhspMBiyLgxKPh7uVzdy21VV+4Cz5pLJo4tZlKKQlRyZ4y1ANiN6nWuKGMpLAAAAX3JlbHMvLnJlbHOtksFOwzAMhu99iij31d2QEEJNd0FIu01oPEBI3DZqE0eJB+XtiZAQDDHYgWOS358/W2m3i5/FM6bsKCi5rhspMBiyLgxKPh7uVzdy21VV+4Cz5pLJo4tZlKKQlRyZ4y1ANiN6nWuKGMpL"
}
```

The encodedFile is a Base64 encoded form of file bytes from the web service. The web service get the file in the server, convert the file to be array of bytes, and then encode the array of bytes to string using Base64, and return the response in JSON format, so the javascript get the string. After I get the the string and decode it (I get the bytes of file), **how I can return it (the bytes) as a file download?** Basically, now I have the bytes of file, and I want to return it to be a file download.

I am using jquery ajax to get the response, get the "status", and get the "encodedFile". Any help or suggestion will be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't get it. Are you looking - inside the browser - to convert "AAAAX3J...." to its native format of, say, '{"a":1,"name":"Matt",....}'?

Comment: Yes, I call the web service from javascript and get the response in JSON format like that. The web service return the result and I check the "status" first, if it is "OK" then I get the "encodedFile". If the "status" is "FAIL", I get the "message". That was the format of the web service response we develop (always return "status" key). So now the "encodedFile" contains the array of bytes (of a file in the server) which has been encoded using Base64. Can I return that array of bytes to a file after decode it from javascript?

Comment: So you take the value of "encodedFile", Base64-decode it, and what do you do with the contents? What does "return that array of bytes to a file mean"?

Comment: FYI, unless there is a strong reason, this is not the best way to go. Why not just use ajax to retrieve the actual file? The Web server and browser will handle over the wire encoding and decoding based on mime-type, and http status codes and headers do a lovely job telling you how successful the request was.

Answer (score 3):

First, we can take the Base64 encoded blob and decode it. Then we take the resultant string, coerce it into a unsigned 8-bit byte array (as it should be), and create a blob from the bytes. Finally, we create a URL for this blob, and set the window.location to it (although you'd probably want to open the blob in a separate tab instead).

```
var data = atob("AAAAX3JlbHMvLnJlbHOtksFOwzAMhu99iij31d2QEEJNd0FIu01oPEBI3DZqE0eJB+XtiZAQDDHYgWOS358/W2m3i5/FM6bsKCi5rhspMBiyLgxKPh7uVzdy21VV+4Cz5pLJo4tZlKKQlRyZ4y1ANiN6nWuKGMpLAAAAX3JlbHMvLnJlbHOtksFOwzAMhu99iij31d2QEEJNd0FIu01oPEBI3DZqE0eJB+XtiZAQDDHYgWOS358/W2m3i5/FM6bsKCi5rhspMBiyLgxKPh7uVzdy21VV+4Cz5pLJo4tZlKKQlRyZ4y1ANiN6nWuKGMpL")
var bytes = new Array(data.length);
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    bytes[i] = data.charCodeAt(i);
}
bytes = new Uint8Array(bytes);
var blob = new Blob([bytes]);
window.location = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
```

Comment: Do you really need intermediate Array?
Why not 'var bytes = new Uint8Array(data.length)'?